# Detect when a window from another application is moved/resized

Tags: cocoa

I'm creating an OS X app that will behave as a companion to some other apps. It will align itself to the side of the topmost app, like a sidebar. Currently I'm just periodically getting a list of open windows and aligning my app to the topmost one. I'm doing this with an NSTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(findHostWindow) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And in findHostWindow, I get a list of windows:

```
CFArrayRef windowDefs =
    CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
```

I search windowDefs to find my ideal host window. It's complicated and sort of irrelevant. Then I find the bounds of the host window:

```
CFDictionaryRef bounds = (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(idealHostWindowDef, kCGWindowBounds);
```

And then I do my snap/dock logic to simulate a sidebar.

There are two concerns of mine:

1. Polling is not efficient performance wise
2. The code is ugly
3. There is a noticeable lag while my window responds to moves/resizes from the host window

Is there a better approach for something like this? Perhaps a system event that alerts apps when any window is moved/resized?

Is there some update method in NSWindow that I can override to perform this before the window is redrawn, rather than my interval-based approach?

Edit: As far as I know, the Accessibility API might offer support for this but it is not in realtime. It only reports *after* the user finishes moving/resizing a window.

Answer (score -2):

I know youre able to manipulate front end of a webpage through javascript. And that includes real time actions. Possibly find a way to add events for when triggered.

http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-javascript-injections-locally-manipulate-websites-you-visit-0130601/

Sorry cant be of more help